# QGIS: how to combine a GeoTIFF with a country border shapefile?

Tags: qgis, python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have two files. A GeoTIFF with different values and a shapefile with country borders of this area. Can I generate with these two files an image with the country borders and the data from the GeoTIFF?

I'm also interested in any other software/scripting solution for this.
I did the second image with matplotlib and basemap but the country borders are wrong (outdated).

Comment: Do you need to generate the image programmatically/scriptwise? Or are you looking for any method at all, even if it's by hand?

Comment: Are you wanting to create an image with spatial reference or just an image?

Comment: @hexamon I need to generate the image

Comment: @artwork21 "only" a image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you would like a image export showing the vector layer and the image below it w/o the vector fill, here are the steps within QGIS:

1. Make sure the country layer is ontop of the raster layer in the Layers table of contents
2. Within country layer Properties>Style>Sinple Fill, change the Fill style to No Brush, and click Ok on all dialogs
3. Zoom into the map for the extent you want to export
4. Select Project menu>Save as Image and change the Save as type as desired (e.g. .jpg, .png, .tif...etc)